# How can I get the sum of items in a column and populate the sum in another column?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm building this invoice form in share point. I'm trying to figure out how can I get the sum and put it in another column. So I need the "Total" of all the items in the column and put it all together in a "Sub Total" column. So I can multiply the subtotal with tax. hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we can get the sum of one column, but cannot fill it into another column in SharePoint Online.

**Get sum of one column:**

1.Click on the column display name

[image]

2.Select **Total** >> **Sum**

[image]